# Como faço um botão desenhar algo novo em uma tela com tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Eu tentei fazer um simulador de dado em Python com Tkinter que mostra o layout do dado na janela depois de rolar. Para isso, eu defini uma função que gera um número aleatório de 1 a 6 e desenha o lado do dado em uma tela dependendo do número que saiu e relacionei essa função a um botão. O problema é que quando aperto o botão, a função não é chamada ou é chamada mas não altera a tela.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as rd 

def rolar_dado( canvas ):
    rand = rd.randint(1, 6)
    if rand == 1:
        dot = canvas.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 2:
        dot = canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        dot2 = canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
    elif rand == 3:
        dot = canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        dot2 = canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        dot3 = canvas.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 4:
        dot = canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        dot2 = canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        dot3 = canvas.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        dot4 = canvas.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
    elif rand == 5:
        dot = canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        dot2 = canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        dot3 = canvas.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        dot4 = canvas.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
        dot5 = canvas.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 6:
        dot = canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        dot2 = canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        dot3 = canvas.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        dot4 = canvas.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
        dot5 = canvas.create_oval(23, 43, 37, 57, fill='black')
        dot6 = canvas.create_oval(63, 43, 77, 57, fill='black')


root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height = 100, width = 100)
square = c.create_rectangle(10, 10, 90, 90, fill='white')
c.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='Rolar', command = rolar_dado(c))
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Sair', command=root.destroy)

b.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
b2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma com que o seu código está estruturado o widget canvas está sendo passado para o método como argumento, neste caso você terá que utilizar uma função anonima (`lambda`) no parâmetro `command` ([callback](https://natorsc.github.io/Tkinter/introducao/eventos/)) do botão.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Canvas."""
import random as rd
import tkinter as tk


def rolar_dado(canvas):
    rand = rd.randint(1, 6)

    # Exibindo o valor para confereir.
    print(rand)

    # Limpando a área de desenho.
    canvas.delete(tk.ALL)

    # Desenhando novamente.
    canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 90, 90, fill='white')
    if rand == 1:
        canvas.delete()
        canvas.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 2:
        canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
    elif rand == 3:
        canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 4:
        canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
    elif rand == 5:
        canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 6:
        canvas.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(23, 43, 37, 57, fill='black')
        canvas.create_oval(63, 43, 77, 57, fill='black')


root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height=100, width=100)
c.create_rectangle(10, 10, 90, 90, fill='white')
c.pack()

# Utilizando função anonima para chamar o método.
b = tk.Button(root, text='Rolar', command=lambda: rolar_dado(c))
b.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Sair', command=root.destroy)
b2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Para **não** utilizar a função anonima (`lambda`), você teria que reestruturar o código para que o widget fique acima da função.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Canvas."""
import random as rd
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height=100, width=100)
c.create_rectangle(10, 10, 90, 90, fill='white')
c.pack()


def rolar_dado():
    rand = rd.randint(1, 6)
    print(rand)
    c.delete(tk.ALL)
    c.create_rectangle(10, 10, 90, 90, fill='white')
    if rand == 1:
        c.delete()
        c.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 2:
        c.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
    elif rand == 3:
        c.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 4:
        c.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
    elif rand == 5:
        c.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(43, 43, 57, 57, fill='black')
    elif rand == 6:
        c.create_oval(23, 23, 37, 37, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 63, 77, 77, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(23, 63, 37, 77, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 23, 77, 37, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(23, 43, 37, 57, fill='black')
        c.create_oval(63, 43, 77, 57, fill='black')


b = tk.Button(root, text='Rolar', command=rolar_dado)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Sair', command=root.destroy)

b.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
b2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Repare que removi as variáveis que foram criadas e não estavam sendo utilizadas.

Com relação a questão de não estar alterando é porque o código não estava limpando a área de desenho (`delete()`), basicamente um circulo estava ficando sobre o outro.